# PHP: Returning a value from a non-native array?

Tags: php, arrays, interop, return

I have a function that's sending a query and receiving an array in the following format:

```
{
    "id1" : 312293.23451244,
    "id2" : 6.03937464,
    "id3" : 1
}
```

Using PHP, how could I return the value for "id1"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = '{
    "id1" : 312293.23451244,
    "id2" : 6.03937464,
    "id3" : 1
}';
$json = json_decode($data, true);
return  $json['id1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use json_decode

```
$str = '{
    "id1" : 312293.23451244,
    "id2" : 6.03937464,
    "id3" : 1
}';

$json = json_decode($str, true);

echo $json['id1'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The above data which you are receiving as a part of response to your query is in

> json

format

So for accessing data from json content you need to use json_decode function defined in php library.

**E.g.**

```
 $result='{
    "id1" : 312293.23451244,
    "id2" : 6.03937464,
    "id3" : 1
 }';

$array=json_decode($result,true);
 echo $array['id1'];
```

It accepts json string as first  argument  and second argument when specified as true will return  an associative array which is more convenient to traverse.

For more details about **json_decode** function please refer the documentation mentioned in following url

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php